# Why is the sun12x22 font not included in Debian by default?

Tags: debian, fonts, console

When setting the console font in Debian using `dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` there is no option to select the Sun console font. The font is available on most other Linux distributions, but the Debian package that contains the console fonts, `console-setup-linux` does not provide it.

Searching the mail list archive doesn't seem to return any message regarding the inclusion or not, but numerous messages where people mention they use it, presumably after some configuration work.

Was this a deliberate decision? Was the reasoning behind including it recorded?

Comment: [This forum post](https://forums.bunsenlabs.org/viewtopic.php?id=4115) claims it’s due to license reasons, but if that were the case the file would have been removed from the `kbd` source package. Unfortunately the `console-data` source package repository is no longer available, so it’s hard to review its detailed history. (`kbd` and `console-data` are the most likely candidates for shipping `sun12x22`.)